# Why is my user model not appearing with the correct name and fields in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0.8 and Python 3.5

I have the following code

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.utils.timezone import now


# Create your models here.
class SiteMemberManager(UserManager):
    pass


class SiteMember(AbstractUser):
    objects = SiteMemberManager()

    MEMBER_STATUS = (
        ('1', 'Pending Approval'),
        ('2', 'Approved'),
        ('3', 'Banned'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=MEMBER_STATUS)    

    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=now)
    abuse_report_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, default=0)    

    fields = ('last_seen', 'abuse_report_count')
```

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import SiteMemberCreationForm, SiteMemberChangeForm
from .models import SiteMember


class SiteMemberAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = SiteMember
    add_form = SiteMemberCreationForm
    form = SiteMemberChangeForm


admin.site.register(SiteMember, SiteMemberAdmin)
```

When I go to the django admin page, there are two problems:

1. My model `SiteMember` does not appear under the django app (instead the model displayed is `Users`
2. The `Users` model does not display any of the fields I implemented on the `SiteMember` model

I have run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` already, and the migrations have been applied (according to the console output).

How do I fix this?

**[[ Clarification ]]**
I have already done the following:

- Restarted the application
- Installed my new app in INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py)
- settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL updated to refer to new (custom) user

Comment: Is your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` (settings.py)?

Comment: Did you change the setting [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yes, I did in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), you can change the fields to display, filters, ordering, etc.

**Example**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SiteMemberAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = SiteMember
    add_form = SiteMemberCreationForm
    form = SiteMemberChangeForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(SiteMember, SiteMemberAdmin)
```

Comment: Your suggested changes did not work. I got the following error: `in unregister
    raise NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model User is not registered`